# Declaring a 2d char array?

Tags: c

Is it possible to declare a 2D array like so:

```
char words[128][25];
```

And then only assign to it like so:

```
int i=0;

while(fscanf(fp,"%s" words[i++]) != EOF){  
 printf("Copied");
}
```

I've seen it in a snippet of code, didn't understand so tried it out and just get a crash from codeblocks when it attempts to run this line. Is it a completely invalid way of using the array when it has been declared like that? It compiles fine it just doesn't run.

Comment: Please show us some compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a legal way of using arrays; the problem appears to be in your while:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s words[i++]) == EOF){
```

You just need a closing quote and comma after the `"%s`.

Comment: @icepack I just tried this, and neither GCC nor Clang throws a warning, even this `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. It seems entirely valid to me.

Comment: Yes missing comma and == not != was just my poor typing writing the question! So its a valid way of using the array, thats what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

As well as what raptor explained, 
you also loop while you are equal to EOF..
this means you will never get the "Copied", UNLESS the file is empty..
You probably mean:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s",words[i++]) != EOF){  
 printf("Copied");
}
```

- Edit:

Referring to Whoz comment, it is true that this is a dangerous code, if your code has more lines than initialized in words, then you will get an exception, other than that, i indeed will state the number of lines(or words) extracted(-1)

Comment: Should note that when this breaks `i` will be one-greater than the number of *successfully* scanned strings.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks, added more explanations(or rather warning) to my answer

Comment: I probably should have elaborated. Imagine a file with a single word. The first iteration will read the word into `words[0]` and increments `i` to 1 and does NOT return EOF. The *second* iteration will *fail* to read a word into `words[1]` and increment `i` to 2, *then* returns EOF which breaks the loop. Bottom line: no matter what this will *always* end with `i` reflecting one-greater than the actual number of strings successfully parsed. Another example, it will be `1` if invoked on an *empty* file (and I hope it is obvious why).